# Trigger action of re-click/double click on first click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have an HTML such that when I click on "Continue" button then an overlay appears. That overlay has "Skip and Continue" button. When I click on "Skip and Continue" button then second overlay appears replacing the first one.

My Expectation is to display the second overlay on the click of Continue button, the first overlay should never appear and the action of "Skip and Continue" should be triggered on the click of Continue button.

I have written below code which is partially working. the Single click on Continue button is not triggering anything however when I re-click or doubleclick the Continue button then second overlay appears. I want second overlay to appears on the single/first click of Continue button.

```
$('button.yelbtn').click(function() {
  $('button.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn').trigger('click');
  $('.flexi-promotion-popup').hide();
});
```

P.S:

Selector for Continue button:

```
$('button.yelbtn')
```

Selector for Skip and Continue Button:

```
$('button.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn')
```

HTML CONTINUE BUTTON :

```
<button id="continue-button" class="yelbtn">
    <span><!-- react-text: 40 -->Continue<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 41 --> <!-- /react-text -->
        <i class="fa icon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">
        </i>
    </span>
</button>
```

DIV APPEARS IN DOM WHEN CONTINUE BUTTON IS NOT CLICKED YET

```
<div class="flexi-promotion-popup">
    <div data-reactroot="">
    </div>
</div>
```

DIV APPEARS IN DOM WHEN CONTINUE BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED (FIRSY OVERLAY)

```
<div class="flexi-promotion-popup">
    <div data-reactroot="" class="ReactModal__Overlay ReactModal__Overlay--after-open popup-overlay-desktop black upgrade-popup">
        <div class="ReactModal__Content ReactModal__Content--after-open popup-container-desktop modal-dialog upgrade-popup-ie" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Flexi-Promotion-Popup">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 id="myModalLabel">
                        <span class="f22">Add flexibility to your travel</span> 
                        <button type="button" class="closeBtn pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="icon-close-stroke"></i>
                        </button>
                    </h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body text-left">
                     <div class="title">
                         <span><!-- react-text: 12 -->BLR<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 13 --> <!-- /react-text --></span>
                             <i class="icon-flight-right"></i>
                         <span><!-- react-text: 16 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 17 -->IXC<!-- /react-text --></span>
                         <span><!-- react-text: 19 --> &nbsp;(<!-- /react-text -->
                             <span>Saver Fare</span><!-- react-text: 21 -->)<!-- /react-text -->
                         </span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media">
                          <div class="media-left">
                              <div class="pp-img text-center">
                                  <img src="/etc/designs/abc-reservation/clientlibs-react/images/popups/unlimited-changes.png" alt="">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media-body bg-flight text-left">
                          <div class="jumbo-text">
                              <span>Make unlimited changes to your booking at additional
                              </span>
                              <span><!-- react-text: 30 -->&nbsp;<!-- /react-text -->
                                  <span>₹&nbsp;354</span><!-- react-text: 32 -->*<!-- /react-text -->
                              </span>
                              <div>
                                  <button class="btn btn-abc"><!-- react-text: 35 -->Add to trip<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 36 --> <!-- /react-text -->
                                      <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                                  </button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-abc skip-cnt-btn ml20" data-dismiss="modal"><!-- react-text: 39 -->Skip and continue <!-- /react-text -->
                                      <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
                                   </button>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <span>
                       <p>*Fare difference applies. For more details,&nbsp;
                           <a href="https://www.goabc.in/information/new-fare-types.html" target="_blank" adhocenable="false">Click here.</a>
                       </p>
                   </span>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

DIV WHEN SKIP AND CONTINUE BUTTON IS CLICKED:

```
<div class="ReactModalPortal">
    <div data-reactroot="" class="ReactModal__Overlay ReactModal__Overlay--after-open popup-overlay-desktop black">
        <div class="ReactModal__Content ReactModal__Content--after-open popup-container-desktop modal-password" tabindex="-1" aria-label="IndiGo" style="border: none; background: transparent;">
            <div class="modal-dialog login-wide gst-wrapper">
                <div class="modal-content indilogin">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title text-left">
                            <img class="indigo-logo" src="/etc/designs/indigo-reservation/clientlibs-react/images/vector-icons/IndiGo-Airlines-Logo-White.svg" alt="IndiGo Airlines Logo">
                                <button class="closeBtn pull-right">
                                    <span class="icon-close-stroke" aria-hidden="true">
                                    </span>
                                </button>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body clearfix">
                        <form>
                            <div class="indilogin-wrappertop">
                                <div class="title_small">Passenger Mobile Number &amp; Email ID
                                </div>
                                <div class="description"><!-- react-text: 15 -->Note: Entering mobile number &amp; email ID is mandatory to proceed for your booking.<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 16 --> <!-- /react-text --><br><!-- react-text: 18 -->*All notifications will be sent to this mobile number and email address.<!-- /react-text -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-table">
                                    <div class="form-cell clearfix">
                                        <div class="telip-code">
                                            <div>
                                                <div name="mobileCountryCode" role="combobox" aria-owns="rw_1__listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-busy="false" aria-live="polite" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" tabindex="0" class="rw-dropdownlist rw-widget">
                                                    <span tabindex="-1" title="open dropdown" aria-label="open dropdown" class="rw-dropdownlist-picker rw-select rw-btn">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="rw-i rw-i-caret-down">
                                                        </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <div class="rw-input">
                                                        <div>
                                                            <span class="iti-flag in">
                                                            </span>
                                                            <div class="selected-dial-code"><!-- react-text: 30 -->+<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 31 -->91<!-- /react-text -->
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="telip-num">
                                            <div><input type="tel" name="mobileNum" value="" placeholder="Enter Mobile No." class="form-control indilogin-wrappertop_mob">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="format">e.g (89687xxxxx)
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="form-cell">
                                    <div>
                                    <input type="email" name="emailId" value="" placeholder="Email Id" class="form-control indilogin-wrappertop_email">
                                    </div>
                                <div class="format">e.g (xxx@gmail.com)
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="gstSwitch text-left">
                                <label class="gstSwitch-switch">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="on">
                                        <div class="slider round">
                                        </div>
                                </label>
                                <span class="gstSwitch-switch_label">GST Information (optional)
                                </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block signin-btn btn-nxt">Next
                                </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can someone help on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try hide/show the continue button

```
$('button.yelbtn').click() {
    $('button.yelbtn').hide();
    $('button.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn').show();
    $('button.btn.btn-indigo.skip-cnt-btn').trigger('click');
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Jay Ganesan, i tried this but it is not working.